# Pubspec yaml version solving failed

Tags: flutter

**Because google_map_location_picker >=4.1.3 depends on google_maps_flutter ^1.1.1 and food_delivery_app depends on google_maps_flutter ^2.0.1, google_map_location_picker >=4.1.3 is forbidden.
So, because food_delivery_app depends on google_map_location_picker ^4.1.6, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because food_delivery_app depends on google_map_location_picker ^4.1.6, version solving failed.)**

> *google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.1   google_map_location_picker: ^4.1.6
>
> mvc_pattern: ^6.6.4+2   global_configuration: ^1.6.0   http: ^0.12.2
>
> html: ^0.14.0+4   shared_preferences: ^2.0.3   flutter_html: ^1.2.0
>
> flutter_svg: ^0.19.0   location: ^3.2.4   flutter_inappbrowser: ^2.0.2
> url_launcher: ^6.0.2   firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
>
> cached_network_image: ^2.5.0   fluttertoast: ^7.1.8
>
> flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.4   intl_utils: ^1.7.0
>
> carousel_slider: ^3.0.0*

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before `dev_dependencies` :

```
dependency_overrides:
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.1
  google_map_location_picker: ^4.1.6
```